# Force re-caching of specific files in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

May I cache-bust specific files based on parameters such as last-modified or other conditions?

Comment: Yes, you may do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own cache files than you can use the **filemtime** function to determine the last modified time of a file.

Comment: Yes but what is the PHP function.